# Why SQL/RDBMS haven't supported applying aggregate function on subquery?

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate-functions, rdbms

A statement like `MAX((SELECT Price FROM Products WHERE Category = 'Food'))` seems completely logical to me (the subquery result set is *equivalent* to a column reference), but why is this generally not supported by SQL and RDBMS?

Is there any technical difficulty to parse such syntax?

Answer (score 1):

It seems simple enough to move the `MAX()` to the subquery:

```
(SELECT MAX(Price) FROM Products WHERE Category = 'Food')
```

As for *why* your version doesn't work . . . well, the designers of SQL might know.  In general, set-returning subqueries are only allowed in a few contexts.  Off-hand, I can think of:

- `IN`/`NOT IN`
- `EXISTS`/`NOT EXISTS`
- operator followed by `ANY`/`SOME`/`ALL`
- `FROM` clauses

In other cases, subqueries are *scalar subqueries* that return only one column and at most one row.  Function arguments are scalar subqueries, not set-returning subqueries.

Comment: What's set-returning subquery? Only heard row/table/scalar subquery myself, as defined in SQL standard. Also, what do you mean by `Function arguments are scalar subqueries...subqueries`. Don't aggregate functions take a column-like thing (either a column or like `Price*Amount`) as its argument? Why scalar subquery as the function argument? Actually, it would be a good feature if aggregate functions can be applied to a table (subquery) (column-wise calculation as supported by almost any matrix-based system today) plus allowing (table) subquery as an argument

Comment: @Nicholas Aggregate names followed by expressions in parentheses are not calls of aggregate functions. The function involved in the meaning of the query containing it maps a group & a function (of a row to a scalar) to a scalar. And the expressions in parentheses don't denote values. SQL syntax is not like everyday arithmetic syntax where all expressions denote a value or even a function call with argument values. SQL syntax is problematically contorted, but there's a historical reason, that at least makes some sense despite problems or alternatives, and that's just how it is/was.